Winload.exe booting process
Wikipedia article about Windows Boot Manager states that it somehow transfers control to winload.exe which in turn loads all the other essential components of Windows.
But how is it able to execute the winload.exe if there is no OS yet to handle .exe format?? Is it somehow different from all the other .exe application I can run when full OS is loaded?
Also when running the winload.exe app it says that "This app can't run on your PC".

Why exactly are you trying to run winload.exe from within Windows?

The outer format matters little – .exe is merely a container format (called PE/COFF) that can hold various kinds of executable code for different platforms. Usually it carries machine code that expects a Windows environment to be available, but that doesn't have to be the case.
Fun fact: The .efi files that UEFI programs use are 100% the same format as .exe files; they just contain code that expects the UEFI environment instead.
So it is entirely possible for there to be a "self-contained" .exe file that contains code which doesn't rely on any OS (or indeed is the OS). In such situations, the bootloader would do the initial job of interpreting the PE file format and loading its contents into memory (all of which is the purpose of the bootloader anyway, regardless of the file format).
Once the machine code is loaded in memory, it no longer matters what file format it came in – the bootloader jumps to the new entry point and the code starts running in the same way.

(The same is often done with the ELF format that e.g. Linux or FreeBSD use for their executable files – some operating systems use the same ELF format for the OS kernel image as well. The bootloader interprets the ELF format, loads its contents in memory, and from there everything proceeds as usual.)

Last I checked the Linux Kernel is an ELF image but not a normal ELF image. It just gets copied to RAM and its start address jumped to. VMM isn't initialized yet so it's not even the normal way to stash the start address.

As an extra fun fact, a modern Linux kernel can be compiled with an EFI boot stub, which effectively makes it a valid EFI PE executable too!
